# Do all four given sentences mean the same thing? Are they grammatically correct?

Tags: past-perfect

1. Have I told you he stopped responding to my letters because **I'd** offended him in the last letter I sent him?
2. Have I told you he stopped responding to my letters because I offended him in the last letter **I'd** sent him?
3. Have I told you he stopped responding to my letters because **I'd** offended him in the last letter **I'd** sent him?
4. Have I told you he stopped responding to my letters because I offended him in the last letter I sent him?

Do all these sentences mean the same thing? Are they grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0):

They're certainly all correct enough that a typical native speaker would find no issue with any of them.

The I/I'd choice for the first instance - "I/I'd offended him" is of little consequence in meaning. It might mean something in context, like making it clear that the question is about a specific occasion on which the speaker might have told the other.

The final I/I'd choice, however, is more important. *I*, used there, suggests that that was the most recent letter that the speaker had sent him at the time they utter (or write) the question. *I'd* allows that it was the most recent letter at some point in the past, but may not be the most recent letter now.